# Python calculations

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that will display total stock of cement, brick, spanner, mirror, and hammer. But the problem  Please help me
  is thsi program keeps showing me' cementinVar is not defined' but i already defined it above as (cementinVar = Tkinter.IntVar())  .

```
def textboxvalue2():

    Total_StockIn = 0



    CementIn = cementinVar.get()
    HammerIn = hammerinVar.get()
    SpannerIn = spannerinVar.get()
    BrickIn = brickinVar.get()
    MirrorIn = mirrorinVar.get()

    CementOut = cementoutVar.get()
    HammerOur = hammeroutVar.get()
    SpannerOut = spanneroutVar.get()
    BrickOut = brickoutVar.get()
    MirrorOut = mirroroutVar.get()

    Total_StockIn = (CementIn + HammerIn + SpannerIn + BrickIn + MirrorIn)+Total_StockIn
    StockInLabel = Tkinter.Label(sub,text='The total  stock in is '+str(Total_StockIn))
    StockInLabel.grid(row=7, column =2)
```

Comment: How are you calling the code? Is this all attached to some update button? I think there's something else at play.

Comment: you want me to put all code here?

Comment: @Teeban, posting a minimal code that demonstrate the problem, will almost always get you better answers, so - yes, post your code.

Answer (score 2):

You define cementinVar in another scope. You have two possible solutions:

1. Use a global variable
2. Use a class variable